# Is there any way I'm able to grab a element ID in EJS and then modify/grab information from it from another js file

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

So basically a quick run down, I've tried using scripts in the ejs file, but all my rendered variables from my express.router file do not work with scripts, so I can't import any variables from other files to use for scripting, so is there any way to grab for example, input information from a input box to then send to a database from a different javascript file, or detect when a user flips a switch on the website and then do something

I have already got express setup and all my router.get/router.post, all I need is to figure out how to be able to control my elements from another javascript file. Thank you.